# EJB 3.1 - @SessionScoped Bean holding Logged In Information - Logout Issue

Tags: java, ejb, resteasy, ejb-3.1, session-scope

I have a @SessionScoped Bean which stores information about the logged in user:

```
@SessionScoped
public class LoggedInUser implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String id;

private String firstName;

private String lastName;

private String email;

private Country country;

private List<String> groups;

private Set<Role> roles;
...
}
```

AuthenticationFilter:

```
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {
    @Inject
    private LoggedInUserTo loggedInUser;

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    // initial = setting log in user informations
    // afterwards several checks (role, same user)    

    }
```

This session scoped bean is injected in several @Stateless beans:

```
    @Inject
    private LoggedInUser loggedInUser;
```

Now I want to logout a user:

```
public void logout() {
    // this.httpServletRequest.getSession(false).invalidate();
    this.loggedInUser = new LoggedInUserTo();
}
```

After that the next time my AuthenticationFilter (also have an injected LoggedInUser) get called, the loggedInUser object is empty and I set new user information. But afterwards if a @Stateless bean get called which contains an injected LoggedInUser object the object is not set correctly. But if I called the service twice the new LoggedInUser informations are set correctly.

What I have to do that all @Stateless beans getting the new LoggedInUser informations?

Comment: Recreate the user first before invalidating the session, so that when the new session is created, the correct user data is available in the newly created httpsession to be injected to sessionscoped beans

Comment: The problem is that the AuthenticationFilter set the LoggedInUser information. While "logout" is called I dont know the "new" LoggedInUser. Workflow: 1) Initial call of the application = read user information from header and set LoggedInUser information --> AuthenticationFilter makes that job. 2) Call "logout" --> I "reset" LoggedInUser Session Scope object. 3) I call the web application again --> AuthenticationFilter set new LoggedInUser informations (Filters know that LoggedInUser object is not set..) and after that another rest service get called but has not the new loggedInUser information

Comment: Then dont allow the CDI to instantiate the LoggedInUserInfo directly. Manage it yourself, by using the filter as a producer, with a sessionscope

Comment: example? Im quite new to this :(

Comment: Could someone tell me what I have to do in the AuthenticationFilter?